# How to avoid overlapping

Tags: php, css, overlap, overlapping

How can I do it responsive, because if I resize the browser, it is overlapping.
Please help
This is my code:

HTML

```
<div style="height:100%" class="image">       
<?php                           
        `$newsbawah = $this->model_utama->view_ordering_limit('newsbawah','id_iklanatas','DESC','0','1');
foreach ($newsbawah->result_array() as $row) { 
$string = $row['gambar'];
if ($row['gambar'] != ''){
        `echo "<img style='width:100%; height:750px;'` 
src='".base_url()."asset/foto_newsbawah/$row[gambar]' />                                
<h4 align='center'>
<span>$row[isi]</span></h4>";
}
} 
?>
```

CSS

```
.image {
position: relative;
width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */  
}
.image h4 {
text-align:center;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
color: #fff;
}
.image span {
width:100%;
height:100%;
float:left;
clear:left;
color: white;
font: 18px/30px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
letter-spacing: -1px;
background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

The image is already responsive if I resize the browser, but the text and the background (the transparent) is overlapping.
Here is the screen shot:

[image: overlapping]

Any help would be very appreciated
Thank you

Comment: I assume the backticks aren't really in your PHP code? You should provide the generated HTML, the PHP here isn't really relevant (unless something is being closed incorrectly)

Comment: Looks like the backticks were an attempt at formatting the code in the question.

Comment: Yes, actually without backticks, I don't know why my question is come with the backticks? Sorry about my mistake